# Python: Adding values to constructor from a method within the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constructor

I have created a sample code interpretting my question:

```
class Calculator:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def addition(self):
        self.value3 = self.value1 + self.value2
        return self.value3

    def square(self):
        return self.value3 ** 3
```

In this code, the function **def addition(self):** has value "**self.value3**" which performs an addition of two values from the constructor and adds the output to constructor.

Also there is a function **def square(self):** that performs square of the value returned in **def addition()** function

Here is the problem, This code block works fine when it proceeds this way

**Scenario 1 - Code execution Successful**

```
obj = Calculator(10, 25) 
print(obj.addition()) ## output = 35
print(obj.square()) ## output = 42875
```

**Scenario 2 - Code Error is observed**

```
obj = Calculator(10, 25)
print(obj.square())
print(obj.addition())
```

**AttributeError: 'Calculator' object has no attribute 'value3'**

#### Question:

A similar approach of Class & Method is written previously by someone in my automation environment and I had to execute the respective methods just to access few values even though I have nothing to run in that method. A lot of cleanup is required as many of the scripts are using the functions. This is affecting my script performance as it consumes lots of time. There are chain of methods interlinked this way and I want to get rid of this for better performance.

Please suggest a better solution for this scenario. Note: These methods are written in a Common Module and is used by multiple Test scripts and are not to be disturbed. I need this to be fixed in order to regularize maintenance effors.

I appreciate your support and value your time, so please comment if you need more info. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `square` could call `addition` if `value3` has not been set?

Comment: call `self.addition` in `__init__`

Comment: Your code shows that `value3` is public. Is this actually the case in your real code? Does anything other than the class access this attribute? Is `addition` an expensive operation in your real code?

Comment: Your `value3` could be a property.

Comment: Basically yes, this is terrible class design. You should not design the class so its methods must be called in a specific order lest it produces errors (that may be appropriate in certain situations, but not here). It's unclear how exactly this can be redesigned without basically rewriting the entire class, since I'll assume this is an abstract example.

Comment: @deceze In my case, this has happened due to historical feature changes where no new modules were written and the code were maintained by multiple periodically by different folks and clean up wasn't done. This is costing a huge effort in maintenance. A fix in the common module would help me in achieving the following: i) High Performance ii) Low Maintenance efforts iii) Avoid Bad Design.
Problem is I have to achieve this without disturbing the Test scripts in my suite. The scenario is more bad than what I have stated in the question. Else, I will also may end up continuing this bad practice.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Code stated is just an interpretation of my environment. I want to fix this. Few of my function uses values from constructor and performs an operation stores back the output to the constructor as a new value. Also, such methods are called within the class among themselves internally. Change in one function will impact the other. This has lead to complexity in solving, as many Test scripts are dependant on this.

Comment: Please be aware that we cannot give you accurate, safe advice unless we understand the constraints your real code still must satisfy. We can "solve" this toy example, but it will likely not be what you need. Also, take note that your use of words (e.g. function instead of method, constructor to imply attributes) is off, so there may be misunderstandings. Your question may be more appropriate for chat.

Answer (score 2):

There are more elegant ways to store intermediate results without introducing redundant attributes, e.g. just call one method from the other and cache results to avoid spurious calculations:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Calculator:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def addition(self):
        return self.value1 + self.value2

    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def square(self):
        return self.addition() ** 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a default value of `self.value3` in the constructor so the order in which the function will be called will not matter anymore.

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = self.addition() # <------- HERE

    def addition(self):
        return self.value1 + self.value2 

    def square(self):
        return self.value3 ** 3
```

Comment: The order still matters. `square` produces a different/incorrect result when called first. Worse, this will silently "work" without an error.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How is that possible?

Comment: Your old version did set `value3` to an inconsistent value. Your new code makes the code in `addition` redundant.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes I corrected that before your first comment.... I agree with the addition redundancy part, I will change that... thanks

Comment: It can be done differently. To call addition in the constructor, maybe is much clear what addition does.